# Getting an error in pycharm ,of TypeError in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

--->This is my one file booking.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class Task(webdriver.Chrome):

    def __init__(self,
          driver_path=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/mank/Documents/webdriver/chromedriver")):
      self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Task, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.maximize_window()
        self.get('https://www.sample.com/')
```

2. this 2nd file of run.py

```
from bot.booking import Task
with Task() as bot:
    bot.landing_page()
    print("exiting..")
```

---->Trying to run by run.py .Please check and let me know ,Thanks

**Error message of :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mank/PycharmProjects/botnew/bot/run.py", line 3, in <module>
with Task() as bot:
File "/home/mank/PycharmProjects/botnew/bot/booking.py", line 14, in __init__
os.environ['PATH'] +=self.driver_path
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WebDriver") to str
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.driver_path` is of type WebDriver but in your code it is treated like a string.
So your code fails in the line `os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path` - just removing the line should fix the current error message.